# R: How to give an argument to survfit function?

Tags: r, function

I am struggeling a bit with finding a solution for this problem. I have created a function to easily change the variable for my Kaplan Meier curve. However, it can't manage to give the argument to the survfit function?

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
    test_function <- function(argument) {
    survfit(surv_object ~ argument, data = data_surv)
    }
    
    test_function(initial_treatment)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'initial_treatment' not found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We could create a formula with `paste`

```
test_function <- function(argument) {
     argument <- deparse(substitute(argument))
    survfit(as.formula(paste("surv_object~", argument)), data = data_surv)
    }
test_function(initial_treatment)
```